# How do I prevent anchor tags for ajax requests from going to the top of the page?

Tags: html, anchor

This seems like a stupid question, but I can't figure it out.  I have some anchor tags on my page that perform ajax functions only, and have no inherent use except for triggering javascript:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="SomeFunction();">Blah</a>
```

How do I prevent clicking on this link from scrolling all the way to the top of the page.  It is causing some annoying UI usability issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="theLink" onclick="SomeFunction();">Blah</a>
```

**JS**

```
//jQuery
$('#theLink').click(function(){
    doSomething();
});

//Regular JS
document.getElementById("theLink").onclick = doSomething;
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/kSxrK/

Comment: `href` attribute is required by W3C specification, but you can use event.PreventDefault(). `$('#theLink').click(function(event){event.PreventDefault();doSomething();});`

Comment: Nothing `javascript:void(0)` can't handle.

Answer (score 1):

Specify a non existing anchor such as `<a href="#nogo" onclick="SomeFunction();">Blah</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Add `return false` to your `SomeFunction()` to the very end :)

```
var SomeFunction = function(){
    //AJAX MAGIC
    return false;
}
```